# Stop button from changing size when changing its contents

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my submit button to switch to a Font Awesome spinner when it is clicked. However, when I do, the button becomes really small, which does not look very pleasant. How can I fix prevent the button from getting smaller?

```js
function refreshreplace() {
  $("#CMSub").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-dialog text-muted">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span>&times;</span>
      </button>

      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Contact me</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Your name:</p>
      <input type="username" id="CMU" name="username">
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Your email:</p>
      <input type="email" id="CME" name="email">
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Your comment/message</p>
      <input type="comment" id="CMC" name="comment">
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="text-centered">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="CMSub" onclick="refreshreplace()">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" onclick="alert('You clicked the tick');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" onclick="alert('You have clicked exit');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on Codepen](http://codepen.io/Riggster/pen/XbOdgR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your css to prevent the size of the button to reduce below the specific value:

```
#CMSub {
    min-width: 60px;
}
```

Here's a codepen with aove code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJGyWy

Answer (score 0):

If you create the object before it is inserted into the document, it won't flash before it is appended.

As well, you can use JavaScript to set the size to it's existing size so it won't change when the content is changed. This way, if the user has settings which override the font-size (for accessibility reasons usually) the size will be correct.

([Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGwWaL))

```css
var spinner = $('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
var button = $("#CMSub");
button.css({'width':button[0].clientWidth + 'px'});
function refreshreplace() {
  button.text('');
  button.append(spinner);
}
```